# How to edit an item sent to pusher?

Tags: c#, pusher

I send items through pusher.
To simplify reading, I need to get back item, and edit it and insert it back.

Is there a way to do so? So far I can send datas with trigger and get it back with bind.

However what if I want to send back and overwrite items I got? Instead of always creating new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. They're events. Modifying it is a brand new event. Pusher's not a data store, it's an event stream.

Include the ID of the item in each event and your user interface can act on the items accordingly.